# Javascript - String.search() return true if string contains any characters NOT matching regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a search for a character in a string NOT matching the regex :

```
password.search(/[`!@@#$%^&*A-Za-z0-9]/i));.
```

Basically, all characters that aren't this regex isn't allowed and I want to know if the user has input any characters that isn't allowed. For example, '\', or any other characters that I might not think of.

I'm pretty sure there's a question similar to this out somewhere, but despite trying to look for it I surprisingly couldn't find it. If this is a duplicate question please link me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/4051471), you could use `?!`:

```js
console.log("valid$\\".search(/(?![`!@@#$%^&*A-Za-z0-9])/i));
console.log("256)128".search(/(?![`!@@#$%^&*A-Za-z0-9])/i));
```

Comment: I accepted your answer at first, but from further investigation it seems your code always returns index > 0 even if there is no illegal character. For example, "256128" returns 6 instead of -1.

Comment: Never mind, instead of checking for < 0 I just did < password.length since if an illegal character didn't exist it always returned the size.

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, I'll try to find a solution for that as well

Answer (score 0):

f you want to exclude a set of characters (some punctuation characters, for example) you would use the `^` operator at the beginning of a character set, in a regex .